# Debian + Huawei E3372h

Tags: debian, huawei

I am trying to get the USB Modem Huawei E3372h to work on Debian.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
lsusb

...
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 12d1:1f01 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
...

lsusb -d 12d1: -v

...
bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
iInterface              4 Mass Storage
...
```

Clearly, the system registers it as mass storage. Now let's try to change that:

```
# makes no difference as far as I can see
rmmod usb-storage
```

Now, let's switch the system:

```
usb_modeswitch -J -v 12d1 -p 1f01

...

lsusb

...
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 12d1:14dc Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
...

lsusb -d 12d1: -v

...
bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
bInterfaceSubClass      6 Ethernet Networking
...
```

Now:

```
modprobe usbserial
modprobe option
echo "12d1 14dc" > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id
```

Now if I check /dev, there are no /dev/ttyUSB*.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Oliver

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl status ModemManager`?

Comment: ModemManager.service - Modem Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ModemManager.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-06-10 16:11:43 EDT; 2min 23s ago
 Main PID: 1422 (ModemManager)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ModemManager.service
           └─1422 /usr/sbin/ModemManager

Comment: Try `sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x12d1 product=0x14dc`

Comment: It now started showing up as /dev/ttyUSB3. I configured it in /etc/wvdial.conf - calling wvdial now results in: `--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATX3
--> Sending: ATQ0
--> Re-Sending: ATX3
--> Modem not responding.`

Comment: Verify the config file : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ZTE_MF626_/_MF636

Comment: I tried a variety of wvdial.conf - they more or less all end up with this: http://pastebin.com/7acb4miw

Comment: Did you try automatic detection with `wvdialconf`?

Comment: Editing `/etc/wvdial.conf'.

Scanning your serial ports for a modem.

Modem Port Scan<*1>: S0   S1   S2   S3   
ttyUSB1<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- failed with 2400 baud, next try: 9600 baud
ttyUSB1<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- failed with 9600 baud, next try: 9600 baud
ttyUSB1<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- and failed too at 115200, giving up.


Sorry, no modem was detected!  Is it in use by another program?
Did you configure it properly with setserial?